# Upload attachment to specific folder

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, forms-7

I am trying to create a job application process in Sharepoint that automatically uploads applicant resumes to specific department folders.

Is it possible in Sharepoint to designate when someone completes a form and attaches their resume to direct the upload to a folder based on the position their applying to?

Answer (score 1):

Your best approach would be to develop an Event Receiver and handle ItemAdded event. In there you could check if there are any attachments added, copy them to a place where you want. If you want to move the attachments to a different location and display them on the form, you will need a custom field for that.